# Datatypes for representing JSON in C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, collections, types

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, and maybe I've just stared too long at it?

Anyhow the problem at hand is to find a good way to represent JSON in C++ and before you read any longer, please note that I am not interested in libraries capable of it, so I want to do it in raw C or C++ (C++11 is fine), no boost, no libjson I know about them and for reasons outside of the scope of this question I can't (/wont) add dependencies.

Now that that's cleared up let me tell you a bit about the problem, and what I have tried this far.

The problem is to find a nice way to represent JSON in C++, the reason this is a bit problematic is that JSON is super-loosely typed, while C++ is really hard typed. consider JSON for a second, what is JSON really capable of typewise?

- Number (e.g. `42` or `3.1415`)
- String (e.g. `"my string"`)
- Array (e.g. `[]`, or `[1,3.1415,"my string]`)
- Object (e.g. `{}` or `{42, 3.1415, "my string", [], [1,3.1415, "my string]}`

So what this mean is that there are two "raw" types, **Number** and **String**, and two container types **Array** and **Object**. The raw types are fairly straight forward, while the container types become tricky in C/C++ as they can and probably will contain elements of different types, so any built in type in the language will not suffice as is, an array can't hold elements of different types. This holds true for STL-types as well (list, vector, array and so on), (unless they have polymorphic equality).

So any container in JSON can hold any type of json-type which is pretty much all there is to it.

***What I've prototyped, or tried and why it wont work***
My first naive thought were to just use templates, so I set up a json-object or json-node type which would then use templates to decide what's in it, so it would then have a structure something like this:

```
template <class T>
class JSONNode {
    const char *key;
    T value;
}
```

While this seemed promising, however when starting to work with it I realized that I ran into troubles when I tried to order the nodes into a container-type (such as array, vector, unordered_map and so on), because they still want to know the type of that JSONNode! if one node is defined as `JSONNode<int>` while another is `JSONNode<float>` well then it will be problematic to have them in a container.

So I move past that, I am not all that interested in keeping them in a container anyway, I'd be rather happy to make them self-aware or what to call it, i.e. ad in a pointer to the next node, but again it gets tricky to figure out the type of the node, and just about here is when I start thinking polymorphism.

***Polymorphism***
Let's just make a virtual `JSONNode` and implement an `JSONNumberNode, JSONStringNode, JSONArrayNode` and `JSONObjectNode` type and they will fit nicely into any container I might want them in, using polymorphism to let them all be JSONNodes.

An example of the code might be in place.

```
class JSONNode {
public:
    const char *key;
    //?? typed value, can't set a type
};

class JSONNumberNode : public JSONNode { 
public:
    int value;
}

class JSONStringNode : public JSONNode {
public:
    const char *value;
}
```

At first I thought this was the way to go. However when I started thinking about how to handle the value-part I realized that I couldn't access the value, even if I wrote a specific function to retrieve the value, what would it return?

So sure I do have objects with different typed values, but I can't really access them without first casting to the proper type, so I could do a `dynamic_cast<JSONStringNode>(some_node);`, but how would I know what to cast it to? RTTI? Well I feel it's getting just a tad bit to complicated at that point, I guess I might be able to use a typeof or decltype figuring out what to typecast it to, but haven't been successful..

***POD types***
So I tried something different, I thought to argue that perhaps I could actually do this in a pod-way. Then I would set up the `value` part to be `void *` and try have some `union` keeping track of the types. However I get the same problem as I already have, namely how to cast data to types.

I feel the need to wrap this question why I didn't go deeper into what I've tried using POD..

So if anyone have a smart solution to how to represent JSON in C++ given this information I would be ever so thankful.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser

Comment: @Ashalynd The OP went to great lengths to state that he is not interested in external libraries.

Comment: @JBentley the question is correct if its for pure learning purposes. If not, **not reinvent the wheel**

Comment: @Manu343726 Irrelevant. The OP wasn't asking for advice on whether or not he should reinvent the wheel. He's stated that that's exactly what he wants to do, and is asking for advice on how to do it.

Comment: See `boost::variant`. If you want reinvent it, but at least check the design.

Comment: @JBentley my comment is only an advise, but if the OP wants to do that I will be glad to answer the question and help him.

Comment: Mainly I've put a lot of time into figuring out a good way to do it, and I would prefer not to just let it be. I would like a solution for learning purposes. I do use libraries which works well and I do believe that I will keep using libraries for json-handling. But I would like to understand how to do it the way I tried to design it and why I can't find a good way to do so.

Comment: Regarding the question, the first solution springing to mind would be to have a generic node type with a field name, field type (enumeration)? + pointer to the field value (and may be the size). And then I'd just have a switch on possible types and access the pointer accordingly. But if someone else already gave a better thought to the same issue, why not reuse the results (by looking within the open-source solutions)?

Comment: @zch to look at `boost::variant` is a good idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last two solutions would both work. Your problem in both of them seems to be extracting the actual values, so let's look at examples. I'll cover the POD idea, for the simple reason that using polymorphy would indeed require RTTI, which IMHO is ugly.

JSON:

```
{
    "foo":5
}
```

You load this JSON file, what you'll get is just your POD "wrapper".

```
json_wrapper wrapper = load_file("example.json");
```

Now you assume the JSON node you loaded is a JSON object. You now have to handle two situations: Either it is an object, or it is not. If it is not, you'll likely end up in an error state, so exceptions could be used. But how would you extract the object itself? Well, simply with a function call.

```
try {
    JsonObject root = wrapper.as_object();
} catch(JSONReadException e) {
    std::cerr << "Something went wrong!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now if the JSON node wrapped by `wrapper` is indeed a JSON object, you can continue in the `try {` block with whatever you want to do with the object. Meanwhile, if the JSON is "malformed", you go into the `catch() {` block.

Internally, you would implement this something like this:

```
class JsonWrapper {
    enum NodeType {
       Object,
       Number,
       ...
    };

    NodeType type;

    union {
        JsonObject object;
        double number
    };

    JsonObject as_object() {
        if(type != Object) {
            throw new JSONReadException;
        } else {
            return this->object;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd use free functions for downcasting, but +1 anyway.

Comment: This is quite similar to how I were going toward the solution using POD (from my question). I failed to find a way to do "typing" and I do believe that this actually provide a solution. Thank you for taking your time to go through it.

Answer (score 12):

I think that you're going on the correct direction with your last approach, but i think that it need to change some concept dessigns.

In all the JSON parsers i've worked so far the decision of choosing the type of the container was on the user-side not on the parser-side, and i think that is a wise decision, why? let's suppose you have a node that contains a number in string format:

```
{
    "mambo_number": "5"
}
```

You don't know if the user would want to retrieve the value as a string or as a number. So, i'll point that the `JSONNumberNode` and the `JSONStringNode` wouldn't fit the best approach. My advice is to create nodes for holding objects, arrays and *raw values*.

All of this nodes will contain a label (name) and a list of nested objects according of its main type:

- `JSONNode`: The base node class wich contains the key and the type of the node.
- `JSONValueNode`: The node type that manage and contains raw values, like the Mambo nº5 listed above, it would provide some functions to read its value, like `value_as_string()`, `value_as_int()`, `value_as_long()`, and so far...
- `JSONArrayNode`: The node type that manage JSON arrays and contains `JSONNode`s accessibles by index.
- `JSONObjectNode`: The node type that manage JSON objects and contains `JSONNode`s accesible by name.

I dont know if the idea is well documented, lets see some examples:

#### Example 1

```
{
    "name": "murray",
    "birthYear": 1980
}
```

The JSON above would be a unnamed root `JSONObjectNode` that contains two `JSONValueNode`s with the labels `name` and `birthYear`.

#### Example 2

```
{
    "name": "murray",
    "birthYear": 1980,
    "fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
}
```

The JSON above would be a unnamed root `JSONObjectNode` that contains two `JSONValueNode`s and one `JSONArrayNode`. The `JSONArrayNode` would contain 8 unnamed `JSONObjectNode`s with the 8 first values of the Fibonacci sequence.

#### Example 3

```
{
    "person": { "name": "Fibonacci", "sex": "male" },
    "fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
}
```

The JSON above would be a unnamed root `JSONObjectNode` that contains a `JSONObjectNode` with two `JSONValueNode`s with the labels `name` and `sex` and one `JSONArrayNode`.

#### Example 4

```
{
    "random_stuff": [ { "name": "Fibonacci", "sex": "male" }, "random", 9],
    "fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
}
```

The JSON above would be a unnamed root `JSONObjectNode` that contains two `JSONArrayNode`, the first one, labeled as `random_stuff` would contain 3 unnamed `JSONValueNode` wich will be of type `JSONObjectNode`, `JSONValueNode` and `JSONValueNode` in order of appearance, the second `JSONArrayNode` is the fibonacci sequence commented before.

#### Implementation

The way i would face the implementation of the nodes would be the following:

The base node would be aware of it's own type (Value Node, Array Node or Object Node) via the member `type`, the value of `type` is provided on construction time by the derived classes.

```
enum class node_type : char {
    value,
    array,
    object
}

class JSONNode {
public:
    JSONNode(const std::string &k, node_type t) : node_type(t) {}
    node_type GetType() { ... }
    // ... more functions, like GetKey()
private:
    std::string key;
    const node_type type;
};
```

The derived classes must provide to the base one the type of node in construction time, the Value Node provides to the user the conversion of the stored value to the type the user request:

```
class JSONValueNode : JSONNode {
public:
    JSONValueNode(const std::string &k, const std::string &v) :
        JSONNode(k, node_type::value) {} // <--- notice the node_type::value
    std::string as_string() { ... }
    int as_int() { ... }
    // ... more functions
private:
    std::string value;
}
```

The Array Node must provide the `operator[]` in order to use it as an array; implement some iterators would be worthwhile. The stored values of the internal `std::vector` (choose the container that you consider the best for this purpose) would be `JSONNode`'s.

```
class JSONArrayNode : JSONNode {
public:
    JSONArrayNode(const std::string &k, const std::string &v) :
        JSONNode(k, node_type::array) {} // <--- notice the node_type::array
    const JSONObjectNode &operator[](int index) { ... }
    // ... more functions
private:
    std::vector<JSONNode> values;
}
```

I think that the Object Node must provide the `operator[]` with string input, because in C++ we cannot replicate the JSON `node.field` accessor, implement some iterators would be worthwhile.

```
class JSONObjectNode : JSONNode {
public:
    JSONObjectNode(const std::string &k, const std::string &v) :
        JSONNode(k, node_type::object) {} // <--- notice the node_type::object
    const JSONObjectNode &operator[](const std::string &key) { ... }
    // ... more functions
private:
    std::vector<JSONNode> values;
}
```

#### Usage

Assuming that all the nodes have all the required functions, the idea of usage of my aproach will be:

```
JSONNode root = parse_json(file);

for (auto &node : root)
{
    std::cout << "Processing node type " << node.GetType()
              << " named " << node.GetKey() << '\n';

    switch (node.GetType())
    {
        case node_type::value:
            // knowing the derived type we can call static_cast
            // instead of dynamic_cast...
            JSONValueNode &v = static_cast<JSONValueNode>(node);

            // read values, do stuff with values
            break;

        case node_type::array:
            JSONArrayNode &a = static_cast<JSONArrayNode>(node);

            // iterate through all the nodes on the array
            // check what type are each one and read its values
            // or iterate them (if they're arrays or objects)
            auto t = a[100].GetType();
            break;

        case node_type::object:
            JSONArrayNode &o = static_cast<JSONObjectNode>(node);

            // iterate through all the nodes on the object
            // or get them by it's name check what type are
            // each one and read its values or iterate them.
            auto t = o["foo"].GetType();
            break;
    }
}
```

#### Notes

I wouldn't use the `Json-Whatever-Node` naming convention, i preffer to place all the stuff into a namespace and use shorter names; outside of the scope of the namespace the name is pretty readable and undesrtandable:

```
namespace MyJSON {
class Node;
class Value : Node;
class Array : Node;
class Object : Node;

Object o; // Quite easy, short and straightforward.

}

MyJSON::Node n;  // Quite readable, isn't it?
MyJSON::Value v;
```

I think is worthwhile to create *null* versions of each object to provide in case of invalid acces:

```
// instances of null objects
static const MyJSON::Value null_value( ... );
static const MyJSON::Array null_array( ... );
static const MyJSON::Object null_object( ... );

if (rootNode["nonexistent object"] == null_object)
{
    // do something
}
```

The premise is: return null object type the case of accesing a nonexistent sub-object in an object node or a out-of-bound acces to an array node.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot, especially since the design/concepts and you provide a very easy to follow approach. And I really appreciate you taking the time to make it so detailed and thorough.

Comment: I'm late for the game, but shouldn't the ctor of class ```JSONValueNode``` and ```JSONArrayNode``` have the same names of the classes?

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey you're late for the game but you're completely and absolutely right, I had a copy-paste typo. I'll fix it right now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Thanks for the post. I intended to write a small json parser in C++ and your post definitely helps a lot!

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus May I ask you a question? It seems that the `std::string key` in `JSONNode` is used as a "handler" for a JSONObject, so that we do not need to use a mapping container such as `std::unordered_map`. But for other situations when there are no keys (i.e. not in a JSONObject), would you just leave the key as a null string or do I have some misunderstading about the algo?

Comment: Wow, you made me look 5yo code! I barely remember anything about what I wrote here back then. But anyways, you're right: the `JSONNode::key` can be *null* (empty string) just because sometimes the JSON nodes are anonymous (i.e: nodes inside a JSON Array). If you look into the Object and Array implementatios they're not using any kind of map (that could be slow! maybe a map would speed things up!) but an `std::vector`, that's because I thought it could be a good idea to save the JSON structure as it is presented, preserving the order.

Answer (score 4):

I know that you said that you aren't interested in libraries, but I've made one in the past for decoding/encoding JSON using C++:

https://github.com/eteran/cpp-json

It's a fairly small library that is header-only, so you may be able to glean from it my strategy.

Essentially, I have a `json::value` which wraps a `boost::variant`, so it can be either one of the basic types (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`) or it can also be an `array` or `object` of course.

There is a little bit of trickiness with forward declarations and dynamic allocation because `array` and `object` contain `value`s, which in turn can be `array`s and `object`s. But that's the general idea.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I do appreciate it, I am not against libraries, and when it's small like this it's helpful as reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in learning, I highly recommending [reading through the jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) -- it's really clean C code with no external json library dependencies.

[Internally, jq keeps the type information in a simple enum](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/jv.h#L4-L27), which obviates most of the compile-time type issues.  Although that does mean you have to build up the basic operations.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a library for a JSON parser. The JSON representation, which is implemented by a template class `json::value`, conforms to the C++ standard library. It's requiring C++11 and standard conforming containers.

The JSON value is based on a class `json::variant`. This one is not unlike `boost::variant` v1.52, but using a more modern implementation (utilizing variadic templates). This variant implementation is much more concise, albeit due to ubiquitously applied template techniques not quite simple. It's just one file, while `boost::variant`'s implementation appears to be unduly complex (do due lack of variadic templates as it was designed). Furthermore, json::variant utilizes move semantics where possible, and implements a few tricks to become quite performant (optimized code is considerable faster than that from boost 1.53).

The class `json::value` defines a few other types, representing the primitive types (Number, Boolean, String, Null). The Object and Array container types will be defined through template parameters which have to be standard conforming containers. So, basically one can choose among several standard lib compatible containers.

Finally, the JSON value wraps a variant member and provides few member functions and a nice API which makes it quite easy to use the JSON representation.

The implementation has a few nice features. For example, it supports "Scoped Allocators". With it, it becomes possible to use an "Arena Allocator" for increased performance when constructing the JSON representation. This requires a conforming and fully implemented container library, which supports the scoped allocator model (clang's std lib does it). Implementing this feature into the variant class, added a whole additional layer of complexity, though.

Another feature is, that it's quite easy to create and access the representation.

Here is an example:

```
#include "json/value/value.hpp"
#include "json/generator/write_value.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    typedef json::value<> Value;

    typedef typename Value::object_type Object;
    typedef typename Value::array_type Array;
    typedef typename Value::string_type String;
    typedef typename Value::integral_number_type IntNumber;
    typedef typename Value::float_number_type FloatNumber;
    typedef typename Value::boolean_type Boolean;
    typedef typename Value::null_type Null;

    Value json = Array();
    json.as<Array>().push_back("Hello JSON!");
    json.as<Array>().push_back("This is a quoted \"string\".");
    json.as<Array>().push_back("First line.\nSecond line.");
    json.as<Array>().push_back(false);
    json.as<Array>().push_back(1);
    json.as<Array>().push_back(1.0);
    json.as<Array>().push_back(json::null);
    json.as<Array>().push_back(
        Object({{"parameters",
        Object({{"key1", "value"},{"key2", 0},{"key3", 0.0}})
    }}));


    std::ostream_iterator<char> out_it(std::cout, nullptr);
    json::write_value(json, out_it, json::writer_base::pretty_print);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string jsonString;
    json::write_value(json, std::back_inserter(jsonString));
    std::cout << std::endl << jsonString << "\n\n" << std::endl;
}
```

The program prints the following to the console:

```
[
    "Hello JSON!",
    "This is a quoted \"string\".",
    "First line.\nSecond line.",
    false,
    1,
    1.000000,
    null,
    {
        "parameters" : {
            "key1" : "value",
            "key2" : 0,
            "key3" : 0.000000
        }
    }
]

["Hello JSON!","This is a quoted \"string\".","First line.\nSecond line.",false,1,1.000000,null,{"parameters":{"key1":"value","key2":0,"key3":0.000000}}]
```

Of course, there is also a parser, which can create such a `json::value` representation. The parser is highly optimized for speed and low memory footprint.

While I would consider the state of the C++ representation (`json::value`) still as "Alpha", there is a complete Objective-C wrapper which is based on the C++ core implementation (namely, the parser) which can be considered final. The C++ representation (`json::value`) still needs some work to finish, though.

Nonetheless, the library may be a source for your ideas: the code is on GitHub: [JPJson](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/JPJson), especially files `variant.hpp` and `mpl.hpp` in folder `Source/json/utility/` and all files in folder `Source/json/value/` and `Source/json/generator/`.

The implementation techniques and the amount of source code might be mind crushing and have been tested/compiled only with modern clang on iOS and Mac OS X - just be warned ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a simplified `boost::variant` with only 4 types in it: an `unordered_map`, a `vector`, a `string` and (optionally) a numeric type (do we need infinite precision?).

Each of the containers would contain smart pointers to instances of the same type.

The `boost::variant` stores a `union` over the types it holds, and an `enum` or index asto which type it has.  We can ask it for the type index, we can ask it if it has one type i  particular, or we canwrite a visitor with distict overrides which the `variant` dispatches the right call to.  (the last is `apply_visitor`).

I would mimic that interface, because I have found it both useful and relatively complete.  In short, reimplement part of `boost`, then use that.  Note that `variant` is a header only type, so it might be light weight enough to just include.